# Stop Safari from loading webpages preview images

Tags: macos, mac, safari, preview, webpage

Everyday, the first time I start Safari, if I go to the history tab, I get the following message :

[image: safari]

How can I stop Safari prompting this message and completely disable the webpages preview?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the preferences to "Empty Page"?

[image]

Comment: Yes, both were already set to Empty.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could wipe out the preferences in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` and/or clear out the `~/Library/Safari` folders and re-open Safari. I'd **backup your bookmarks** before trying the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now a Mac pro but I searched a bit and found this:

http://roderick.dk/blog/2009/08/03/disable-webpage-preview-images-in-safari-4-final/

Hope this will help!

Comment: That's what I did sometimes ago, but I still have this annoying message …

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking "Add previews now" to prevent the dialog from showing up in the future, and THEN follow the steps mentioned in [@r0ca's link](http://roderick.dk/blog/2009/08/03/disable-webpage-preview-images-in-safari-4-final/)—making sure Safari is not running as you're doing so, since it'd likely overwrite those preferences when it quits.